# Why is ASP.net forms authentication logging me off (when not connecting directly on my box)?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I've got an ASP.net 2.0 application on my server at work.  When I'm on the box and browsing (either http://serverName or http://localhost) the site I can login with forms authentication and navigate the site with no trouble.

The instant I browse that server from my intranet I can still login, but anytime I click any links on the homepage I'm asked to login again.  I can get to the home page, so authentication is working, but I'm immediately redirected to the login page after that.  I'm using the same userid in both cases.

It's not a case of browser cookies not being enabled, this happens from several different workstations, using IE and Firefox.  I have another ASP.Net app running on my same machine, and it works fine either locally or outside.  (It's an older version of the same app, also using forms authentication.)

I'm using inproc sessions, not cookieless sessions either.  Essentially the session setting that come straight out of the box.

The forms authentication setup on the two virtual directories (old and new app) is the same as best I can tell, and I don't have a firewall running on the machine.

I'm at a loss to explain this, and if you have some suggestions I can look into I'd be grateful.  Thanks!

**Edit**: It appears this happens when I have the  tag in my web.config set to "On" or "RemoteOnly".  I see from [ieHttpHeaders](http://www.blunck.info/iehttpheaders/iehttpheaders.html) that there's a call to WebResource.axd, then the next page called is my custom error page.  When I set customErrors to off, things work as expected.  So it appears the error is originating from WebResource.axd in some way.

Unfortunately, the custom error page's Page_Load method has very little information sent into it.  The event args are null and the sender is ASP.error_aspx, but I can't see much info in it.

If any of this rings a bell and if you have any ideas to try as far as debugging goes, I'm happy to listen.  Thanks again.

Comment: Any luck solving this? Are there any exceptions in the system log? Can you post the IIS log for this transaction to see exactly what's been called and the status codes?

Comment: Hi Greg-- thanks for your interest.  In fact, I couldn't find any exceptions in the system or other logs.  

As it turns out we never did figure this out, as switching the customErrors tag in web.config to "Off" from "On" or "RemoteOnly" was good enough to hold us.  Wish I had better info to share.  (Most likely our custom error routine was throwing some buried-deep exception, but we couldn't figure it out.)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. This is very weird.

Answer (score 1):

I was upgrading an old site to use dynamic data both of these sites use forms authentication and I was testing them locally.

**Problem:**
When comparing **Site A** & **Site B** in my browser I found when I switched from using **Site A** to Use **Site B**  I had to Re-Login to **Site B** and vice-versa.

**Solution:**
In my investigation to this I discovered what was causing this phenomena. Site A & Site B had the same authentication cookie name

Site A

```
<forms name="form1" loginUrl="login.aspx" path="/"  >
</forms>
```

Site B

```
<forms name="form1" loginUrl="login.aspx" path="/"  >
</forms>
```

I changed the names to be unique and that solved the issue.

Site A

```
<forms name="sitea" loginUrl="login.aspx" path="/"  >
</forms>
```

Site B

```
<forms name="siteb" loginUrl="login.aspx" path="/"  >
</forms>
```

**Note**: http://**localhost**/SiteA & http://**localhost**/SiteB are hosted on the same website (**localhost**) so the authentication cookie was being overidden.